# Max number of stocks held on given date range

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, date-range

I have historical traded data, with the date of entry, date of exit, and stock name.

I want to know the maximum number of stocks that were held in any given date range.  I am having this data in MySQL and in python pandas.

My dataset:

```
    entry_time  exit_time         stk
272 2020-06-10 2020-06-23    SHANKARA
197 2020-06-11 2020-06-25    PNCINFRA
85  2020-06-11 2020-06-25  DYNAMATECH
171 2020-06-15 2020-06-29     MANINDS
199 2020-06-16 2020-06-24     ASTERDM
241 2020-06-18 2020-06-29     JKPAPER
130 2020-06-18 2020-06-23  SOMANYCERA
159 2020-06-18 2020-06-25  EVERESTIND
212 2020-06-18 2020-07-01    JSLHISAR
295 2020-06-19 2020-06-25  IBVENTURES
133 2020-06-19 2020-07-02     FIEMIND
123 2020-06-19 2020-06-23    SUPRAJIT
118 2020-06-19 2020-07-01  NRBBEARING
97  2020-06-19 2020-06-24        SPAL
261 2020-06-19 2020-06-29   DALBHARAT
50  2020-06-22 2020-07-06   SANGINITA
150 2020-06-22 2020-07-06         BBL
55  2020-06-22 2020-07-06  SHARDAMOTR
169 2020-06-22 2020-07-06   BALAMINES
12  2020-06-22 2020-06-25   KIRLOSIND
284 2020-06-22 2020-07-06  NATCOPHARM
236 2020-06-23 2020-07-06   QUICKHEAL
69  2020-06-23 2020-07-07        HMVL
220 2020-06-24 2020-07-08      ASTRAL
42  2020-06-26 2020-07-10     MENONBE
260 2020-07-06 2020-07-16         BSE
105 2020-07-07 2020-07-20   GARFIBRES
35  2020-07-16 2020-07-30       SATIA
218 2020-07-17 2020-07-31   THYROCARE
8   2020-08-04 2020-08-07    CREATIVE
```

output should give me count of max number of stocks held between any given day.

for example from above data we can see on 2020-06-15 we had 4 stocks in our portfolio . hence if 4 is the max number of stocks held output should show me 4.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your output should look like?

Comment: Provide some combination of "given date range -> maximum number of stocks" (or maybe 2-3 combinations) with the explanations.

Comment: thanks for suggestions,  i have added it

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can handle this by keeping track of ins-and-outs, and then doing a cumulative sum:

```
with io as (
      select entry_time as dt, 1 as inc
      from t
      union all
      select exit_time  + interval 1 day as dt, -1
      from t
     )
select dt, sum(inc) as change_on_day,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dt) as active_on_day
from io
group by dt
order by active_on_day desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0fa20f93e8ea9688eb925d345fd7987) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create a group of the count of all `entry_time` by `exit_time` and then merge the dataframe back on itself to figure out the value to be subtracted (count of stocks that exited for each `entry_time`).
2. However, you cannot just subtract the value of that particular row from the row number (the row number is `df.index + 1`, but you need to first do `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` as I have done in the first line of code). Then, you need to subtract the cumulative sum by using `.cumsum()`.

---

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
s = (pd.merge(df,
              df[['exit_time']].assign(exit_count=df.groupby('exit_time')['entry_time'].transform('count'))
                                                   .rename({'exit_time':'entry_time'}, axis= 1)
                                                   .drop_duplicates(subset='entry_time')
              ,on='entry_time', how='left'))['exit_count'].fillna(0)
df['COUNT'] = df.index + 1 - s.cumsum()
df
Out[1]: 
    entry_time   exit_time         stk  COUNT
0   2020-06-10  2020-06-23    SHANKARA    1.0
1   2020-06-11  2020-06-25    PNCINFRA    2.0
2   2020-06-11  2020-06-25  DYNAMATECH    3.0
3   2020-06-15  2020-06-29     MANINDS    4.0
4   2020-06-16  2020-06-24     ASTERDM    5.0
5   2020-06-18  2020-06-29     JKPAPER    6.0
6   2020-06-18  2020-06-23  SOMANYCERA    7.0
7   2020-06-18  2020-06-25  EVERESTIND    8.0
8   2020-06-18  2020-07-01    JSLHISAR    9.0
9   2020-06-19  2020-06-25  IBVENTURES   10.0
10  2020-06-19  2020-07-02     FIEMIND   11.0
11  2020-06-19  2020-06-23    SUPRAJIT   12.0
12  2020-06-19  2020-07-01  NRBBEARING   13.0
13  2020-06-19  2020-06-24        SPAL   14.0
14  2020-06-19  2020-06-29   DALBHARAT   15.0
15  2020-06-22  2020-07-06   SANGINITA   16.0
16  2020-06-22  2020-07-06         BBL   17.0
17  2020-06-22  2020-07-06  SHARDAMOTR   18.0
18  2020-06-22  2020-07-06   BALAMINES   19.0
19  2020-06-22  2020-06-25   KIRLOSIND   20.0
20  2020-06-22  2020-07-06  NATCOPHARM   21.0
21  2020-06-23  2020-07-06   QUICKHEAL   19.0
22  2020-06-23  2020-07-07        HMVL   17.0
23  2020-06-24  2020-07-08      ASTRAL   16.0
24  2020-06-26  2020-07-10     MENONBE   17.0
25  2020-07-06  2020-07-16         BSE   12.0
26  2020-07-07  2020-07-20   GARFIBRES   12.0
27  2020-07-16  2020-07-30       SATIA   12.0
28  2020-07-17  2020-07-31   THYROCARE   13.0
29  2020-08-04  2020-08-07    CREATIVE   14.0
```

Then, to summarize by max stock per `entry_time`, you can use `.groupby()`:

```
df = df.groupby('entry_time')['COUNT'].max().reset_index()
df
Out[2]: 
    entry_time  COUNT
0   2020-06-10    1.0
1   2020-06-11    3.0
2   2020-06-15    4.0
3   2020-06-16    5.0
4   2020-06-18    9.0
5   2020-06-19   15.0
6   2020-06-22   21.0
7   2020-06-23   19.0
8   2020-06-24   16.0
9   2020-06-26   17.0
10  2020-07-06   12.0
11  2020-07-07   12.0
12  2020-07-16   12.0
13  2020-07-17   13.0
14  2020-08-04   14.0
```

Comment: sorry unfortunately this is returning wrong output. another solution in my mind. logically we can take min , max date  from both columns combined and populate list of dates between min and max date range. then we can run a for loop to get count of rows  from our main dataframe where that date falls between entry and exit date range

Comment: @RamDubey can you please post your expected output in your question? You most likely don't need to use a for loop.

Comment: @RamDubey Can you give an example of something that would be wrong output, or better yet, can you copy and paste my answer into your question and change the data that is wrong, so I can see why?